# How to focus arrow keys on ListView while writing in a TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple Windows Form containing a TextBox and a ListView.

I want to allow the user to write text into the TextBox while focusing on the ListView (typing text into the TextBox while controlling the ListView with the keyboard arrow keys).

Also, I want to be able to handle "special" key presses such as Esc and Return.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not clear your question; what is your actual need?

Answer (score 0):

On KeyDown event of TextBox you can find which key was pressed by user with e.Key like this,

```
    private void txtName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)// Key.Escape, Key.Return
        {
            //What is your need..................
        }
    }
```